# My acer netbook screen is white

Tags: laptop, laptop-display

I dropped my acer netbook and now the screen is white. I can hook my comp up to another monitor and that works but the acer screen is just white light. Is it an expensive fix?

Comment: Take it to a computer shop and let them test the screen. Depending on the model, you may be spending a few hundred bucks on a new screen.

Comment: If you have the confidence/are out of warranty anyway/feel like experimenting, a cheaper alternative is to buy a panel on e.g. Ebay and fit it yourself. It is not especially difficult to install, and you will spend a lot less money.

Answer (score 1):

Don't panic. Take it to the nearest electronics store and have them look at it.